# I want to secure a route with role admin

Tags: reactjs, symfony

How do I send a token from the back-end to the front-end to secure routes? I'm using Symfony 5.4 and React 18.16

I'm trying to create a admin role and secure that route. I can see my token on Postman, but then, what do i do ?  a custom controller in Symfony? a component in React?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some ways to send token from server to client base on your mechanisms security.

Example with JwtToken, when user login success, server will return token to client in response and client (ReactJS) save token to LocalStorage and set this token into `Authorization` in `headers` of all api (if you use axios, so will config interceptor). This is normal way and less security because token can be read by script.

Other way when use login success, server will set token to cookie with some config such as: httpOnly = true (This restrict javascript read token), domain = your domain (enable domain or subdomain can use token). With this way, about client side you don't need write more any thing because when call api, headers of api will be auto insert all cookie of your domain and sent it to server.

About server side, you need to write a middleware or filter to check token (reference at [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html)). This middleware get token from header, valid token and throw HttpException 401 for error authentication or 403 for error authorization.